# Ensure docker pulls most current image

Tags: virtualization, docker, containers, docker-registry

Assuming I have registered a repo at Docker Hub, called MyRepo. 
Assuming I am working on a Docker image called MyImage.
Assuming I have configured Docker Hub to build images from Dockerfiles available in my GitHub repo.

Problem:
(I usually use the docker run shorthand instead of pulling, creating and starting.)
Once I pull the image from Docker Hub, docker always uses the locally saved image for creating containers. 
Question:
Is there a way to configure Docker to always check for newer versions of the image at Docker Hub and, if applicable, pull before creating containers?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way to do this in docker, but you could write a simple bash script or set an alias for `docker run` which does a `docker pull $IMAGE` beforehand. If you already have the latest image docker will not download it again.

Comment: You're right. There's a long time open issue in Docker issue tracker for that: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13331